# Hadoop Azure: Issue when authenticating storage account using MSI in App Service Plan (Azure Functions)

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-functions, azure-container-apps

This is similar to what has been discussed here: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@hadoop.apache.org/msg24204.html

The MSI endpoint that the hadoop-azure client expects (I think) is applicable only for VM's and not for functions. So, I retrieved the MSI endpoint from the environment variable `IDENTITY_ENDPOINT`

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth");
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.MsiTokenProvider");
if (System.getenv("IDENTITY_ENDPOINT") != null) {
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.msi.endpoint", System.getenv("MSI_ENDPOINT"));
}
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.msi.tenant", "xx");
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id", "yy");
spark.parquet.read("")
```

Running  above gives me the following error:

> Status code: -1 error code: null error message: Auth failure: HTTP
> Error 400; url='http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token' AADToken: HTTP
> connection to http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token failed for getting
> token from AzureAD.; contentType='application/json; charset=utf-8';
> response '{"error":{"code":"UnsupportedApiVersion","message":"The HTTP
> resource that matches the request URI
> 'http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token' does not support the API version
> '2018-02-01'.","innerError":null}}'org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException:
> HTTP Error 400; url='http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token' AADToken:
> HTTP connection to http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token failed for
> getting token from AzureAD.; contentType='application/json;
> charset=utf-8'; response
> '{"error":{"code":"UnsupportedApiVersion","message":"The HTTP resource
> that matches the request URI 'http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token'
> does not support the API version '2018-02-01'.","innerError":null}}'
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.executeHttpOperation(AbfsRestOperation.java:274)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.completeExecute(AbfsRestOperation.java:217)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.lambda$execute$0(AbfsRestOperation.java:191)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.impl.IOStatisticsBinding.trackDurationOfInvocation(IOStatisticsBinding.java:464)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:911)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:892)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getIsNamespaceEnabled(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:358)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:932)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:609)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:599)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1760)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.exists(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1177)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$4(DataSource.scala:784)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$4$adapted(DataSource.scala:782)
> at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
> at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:678)
> at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:467)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
> Caused by:
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException:
> HTTP Error 400; url='http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token' AADToken:
> HTTP connection to http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token failed for
> getting token from AzureAD.; contentType='application/json;
> charset=utf-8'; response
> '{"error":{"code":"UnsupportedApiVersion","message":"The HTTP resource
> that matches the request URI 'http://169.254.138.2:8081/msi/token'
> does not support the API version '2018-02-01'.","innerError":null}}'
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenSingleCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:430)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenCall(AzureADAuthenticator.java:306)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenFromMsi(AzureADAuthenticator.java:154)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.MsiTokenProvider.refreshToken(MsiTokenProvider.java:57)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AccessTokenProvider.getToken(AccessTokenProvider.java:50)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAccessToken(AbfsClient.java:1055)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.executeHttpOperation(AbfsRestOperation.java:256)
> ... 23 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is applicable for `azure-functions` as well as `azure-container-apps`. The behavior may be different for other managed services.

[hadoop-azure](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#Custom_OAuth_2.0_Token_Provider) provides a mechanism for custom token provider.

```
package org.acme;

import com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

class CustomToken implements  org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.extensions.CustomTokenProviderAdaptee {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private String accountName;
    private volatile AccessToken token;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Configuration configuration, String accountName) {
        log.info("Custom Token to be initialized. Config: " + configuration + ". AccountName: " + accountName);
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccessToken() {
        if (token != null && OffsetDateTime.now().isBefore(token.getExpiresAt().minusHours(2))) {
            return token.getToken();
        } else {
            log.info("token has expired or not been set. " +  token);
            fetchAndSetToken();
            return token.getToken();
        }
    }

    private void fetchAndSetToken() {
        DefaultAzureCredential creds = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                .build();
        TokenRequestContext request = new TokenRequestContext();
        request.addScopes("https://" + accountName);
        this.token = creds.getToken(request).block();
        log.info("Token has been set. Expires at: " + token.getExpiresAt() + " . " + token.isExpired());
    }

    @Override
    public Date getExpiryTime() {
        return new Date(token.getExpiresAt().toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

---

To further debug: ssh onto the container apps or azure functions vm.

To obtain the MSI Secret: `echo $MSI_SECRET`. And then obtain the token by making a curl call to:

```
curl -v -H "X-IDENTITY-HEADER: msi_secret_from_above" "http://127.0.0.1:42356/msi/token/?resource=https://storage-account-name.dfs.core.windows.net/&api-version=2019-08-01"
```

The java code earlier written replicates the above behavior. I found this link useful to understand MSI. https://dev.to/stratiteq/managed-identity-how-it-works-behind-the-scenes-co4